# Is it possible to install an APK within your app's storage space to prevent it from showing up on the phone's start screen?

Tags: android, google-play

The app I'm working on is an aggregator of sorts. The company coordinates with other app developers, gets their permission to market and push freemium versions of their apps within our app.

Basically, if you sign up with our app and pay `$x`, you get monthly access to a bunch of other apps that would've been more expensive if subscribed to directly.

This works but our app ends up needing to side-load the apps and it shows up in the app list and on the *Home screen*.

But, since we receive an authentic version of the apps from the developers themselves, is it possible for us to install the app on the user's phone without it showing up on the user's Home screen?

The idea is to ensure it doesn't look like we just helped them install an app on their phone.

We want those apps to be exclusively accessible via our app. It shouldn't be accessible via the phone's home screen or app list screen.

I imagine it could be possible since I've seen launchers do it. Some launchers come with smaller apps installed within them that's accessible only via their launcher platform. I'm not too sure how that's achieved though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your other apps developer to ship their app without the launcher category in the manifest file.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

**Remove** the above line from the launcher activity of other applications to prevent it from showing in launcher screen.

Comment: Your instructions will remove the app's icon from the launcher. Your instructions will not affect whether the app shows up in the list of installed apps.

Answer (score 0):

> It shouldn't be accessible via the phone's home screen or app list screen.

While you can ask the developers to take steps to prevent their app from showing up in the launcher, you cannot prevent the installed app from showing up in the list of installed apps.

> The idea is to ensure it doesn't look like we just helped them install an app on their phone.

Then do not install an app on their phone.

> Some launchers come with smaller apps installed within them that's accessible only via their launcher platform.

If they do not show up as apps in the list of installed apps, then those are not apps, from an Android standpoint.